# How do I strike-through/strikeout a single line of a textblock when updating

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a text block attached to an event listener, when a new message is passed in I want it to create a new line and strikeout the previous one although I'm having difficulties. I know I can text the entire textblock to add a strikeout but I don't want the string I'm appending to be stroked out. This is the closest I've got but as it's a WPF form the tags don't apply (not to mention if it did it would apply  tags over and over:

```
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            String oldInstruction = String.Format("<del>{0}</del>", txtInformation.Text); // strikeout somehow
            txtInformation.Text += oldInstruction + System.Environment.NewLine + instruction;
        }));
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like it could use a MVVM approach - having a list of messages with a property controlling the strikeout, then using something like ItemsControl to display them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can use Inlines in textblocks ... these are used to provide different formatting to different texts in a text block...

you can do something similar to ....

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Line1." />
    <Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="Line2. " />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```